# Center swiftUI view in HStack and align accessory view to first baseline text

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to accomplish two things. First, id like to align the "Swift View" to be in the center. Second, id like to align the view to the right to `firstTextBaseline` of the first view (`Text`).

Im not sure what the best way to do this is, but ive found several similar postings, but I cant figure out how to get it to look like this:

[final desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pViFO.png)

My current code looks like this but I dont like it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      VStack(alignment: .subCentre) {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Text("Swift View")
              .foregroundColor(.white)
              .font(.largeTitle)
              .padding(35)
              .background(
                LinearGradient(
                  colors: [.orange, .red],
                  startPoint: .topLeading,
                  endPoint: .bottomTrailing
                )
              )
              .cornerRadius(20)
              .alignmentGuide(.subCentre) { d in d.width/2 }
          Text("test")
        }
        //Geometry reader automatically fills the parent
        //this is aligned with the custom guide
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            EmptyView()
        }
        .alignmentGuide(.subCentre) { d in d.width/2 }
      }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Adding a GeometryReady at the bottom seems janky. Cant be the best way to do things.

Comment: please add code for your custom alignment `.subCentre`, otherwise it is not reproducible.

Comment: Add your declaration of `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two quite easy ways to achieve this layout:

**1. Balance the `HStack` with a hidden copy of the accessory view on the left side**

This technique ensures that the main view is exactly centered.... or it least it will be, if the two copies of the accessory view have exactly the same width - more on this point below.

Alignment to the baseline of the main text is achieved using `.firstTextBaseline` as you were using before. It's perhaps a surprise that this works, because you might think the first text is now the hidden block, but I think the way it works is that it chooses the text that is vertically highest (nearer the top) in its default position. Since the main block has a much larger font, this means it wins and is used for baseline alignment.

```swift
var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
        Text("test").hidden()
        Text("Swift View")
            // modifiers as before, but without alignmentGuide
        Text("test")
    }
}
```

If the accessory view contains text that wraps then it is conceivable that the copies might wrap differently and therefore they might have slightly different widths. The solution in this case is to add `.fixedSize()` to the main content and `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)` to the two accessory views, so that they both occupy half the remaining width.

**2. Show the accessory view in an overlay**

This time, a hidden copy of the main content is used to establish the base footprint, with center alignment by default. The whole `HStack` is then shown in an overlay.

With this approach, the overlay overflows the bounding frame of the underlying content, so it might need to be given space to overflow (by default, it would overlap anything that appears to the right).

```swift
var mainContent: some View {
    Text("Swift View")
        // modifiers as before, but without alignmentGuide
}

var body: some View {
    mainContent.hidden()
        .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                mainContent
                Text("test")
            }
            .fixedSize()
        }
}
```

The result is the same in both cases:

[image: Alignment]

Just for completeness, another way to do it would be to create your own custom `Layout`. But it's not so easy.